# Smalltalk copy of object and work on a variables

Tags: object, copy, return, smalltalk

Hi I need to do a small program in Smalltalk, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
So, I have an abstract class Class1, which has few subclasses for example Class2.

What I want to do is to create object in method Class1 class as a copy of them self, work on it and after return in. I know it is might to sound weird but I am horrible in explanation.

My method looks like this:
(value is a variable from Class1)

```
|temp|

temp:= self DeepCopy.
1 to: temp >> arrayName size do:
[i: | tenp >> arrayName at i: put (temp >> arrayName at: i) + 10].

^temp
```

This is my first program in Smalltalk and of course it is not working, maybe you know this language and you could help me a little bit.

Thank you

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Edit

my method

```
move: vector

    | temp |
    temp :=self deepCopy.

    1 to: temp points size do:
    [:i |  temp points at: i put: ( temp points at: i) + vector].

    ^temp .
```

And usage

```
geo_1:=(Triangle new) initialize 10.
geo_2:= geo_1 move: 2@2
```

Comment: OK. And what is not working? What error do you get?

Comment: @Leandro Caniglia error about the unhandled exception: Message not understood: #deepCopy

Comment: Try `copy`. It should work.

Comment: @Leandro Caniglia with copy there is an error about the points array

Comment: Which one. Please try to be more explicit.

Comment: with copy, a Message with selector: #points and arguments: #()

Comment: message not understood

Comment: So, as you see, `points` is a message that you are sending to `temp`. If `temp` does not understand this message, maybe it could be that its class has no `points` method? You cannot access the instance variables of another object, except by sending a message. That's the rule in Smalltalk, all you can do is send messages.

Comment: @aka.nice I see, I am not familiar with Smalltalk, what do you mean by saying send the message, could you give some example

Comment: Examples: `1 + 2` is interpreted as sending the message #+ with parameter 2 to the (Small)Integer 1. `temps points` means send the message #points to the object pointed by variable named temp. So you should define a message `points ^points` in this class if you want to expose the instance variable for public consumption... Smalltalk is message-oriented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to clone an object, modify the clone, and then return the modified copy. Am I right? If so, let me provide you with some guidance:

1. You could indeed implement the cloning mechanism using `deepCopy`. Note however that case matters in Smalltalk so please don't send the `DeepCopy` message because (most likely) it will not exist, use `deepCopy` instead:

   ```
   temp := self deepCopy.
   ```
2. Names are crucial for readability. Therefore, avoid the use of of generic variables such as `temp`. In this case I would suggest renaming the temporary to `clone`, which better reflects your intention:

   ```
   | clone |
   clone := self deepCopy.
   ```

   See what I mean? The name `clone` on the left tells the reader *what* you are doing. The expression `self deepCopy` tells *how* you are doing it.
3. In Smalltalk you access an object property by sending it a message. There is no dot notation or `>>` or anything for this. To send an message just leave a space in between:

   ```
   clone arrayName
   ```

   As a good friend of mine says, *In Smalltalk the send operator is the white space*.
4. Try not to compose keyword messages. Use temporaries instead and give them revealing names:

   ```
    value := clone arrayName at: i.
    clone arrayName at i: put: value + 10
   ```

   Note that the name `value` that I'm using is not a good one because is too generic. If your array contains prices you should use `price` instead. If your array contains points, use `point`, etc.
5. Regarding item 3 above, the only way to access an object property from the outside is to send the object a message. In your case, you want to read the `points` of your object, so you need to provide a `#points` method that answers with the collection of points the object somehow has. For example, if your class has a `points` instance variable define a method with that name as

   ```
   points
     ^points
   ```

   (in the items above I've used `arrayName` instead because that was the selector you used initially in your question.)

Comment: Thank you Leonardo for your respond, I am grateful. according to the respond, yes you have right I want to make a copy and modify it, return it. I change the code but it is still not working. I will try to say something more about what I want to do, maybe the problem is somewhere else. So I want to create new object of that is a modified copy of a previous one. First I am creating something like this : variable1:=(Class2 new) initialize: 10. And now I want to create my modified object variable2:=variable1 methodName: argumentThatChangeSmg. (I use that kind of names only for a demonstration)

Comment: @Eken paste a fragment of your code in the question so we can help you.

Comment: @Leonardo Cainglia thanks for the edit, I have no idea why but it still no working. There is no error, simply, the new object modified and also orginal is changing

Comment: That's because of the `copy`. I would suggest asking a new question for this because `copy` requires a lot more or considerations.

Comment: @Leonardo Cainglia Yes, you are right. I solved the problem, insted of copy I used simply a new object and after the ability to access the value of it I changed it to looks like a perfect copy. Thank you very much, without you I am sure it would takes more time for me